# Start perforce checkout from command line

Tags: perforce

I try to achieve a checkout from command line by using perforce helix.

It works with p4 edit.

But what i want is to open the regular window when you right click on files and click "checkout".

p4vc can open many window but what is the argument for this checkout window ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The window you're talking about is just P4V; there's no stand-alone dialog for that.